# Python 3 invalid syntax error when reading file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am attempting to learn python 3 and there is an exercise in the book that requires us to supply a filename on the command line when invoking the script. However, I am getting a syntax error and I cant figure out what I am doing wrong.

The environment: Windows 10 laptop running Python 3.8.0 x64 bit

The script:

```
from sys import argv

script, filename = argv

txt = open(filename)

print("Here's your file %r" % filename)
print(txt.read())

print("Type the filename again: ")
file_again = input("> ")

txt_again = open(file_again)

print txt_again.read()
```

The commandline input:

```
PS E:\~Python Scripts> python .\ex15.py ex15_sample.txt
```

The error:

```
    PS E:\~Python Scripts> python .\ex15.py ex15_sample.txt                                                                   File ".\ex15.py", line 15
    print txt_again.read()
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Python 3 uses a print function `print(text_again.read())`

Comment: Look at how that `print` line differs from the other lines where you used `print`. Can you spot the difference just from that?

Comment: as @BrendanAbel , and Martijn Pieters♦ already mentioned, it is a simple parentheses error that is required to be fixed. I suggest you are not using any IDEs that would solve that?

Comment: Thank you all! I can't believe I didn't notice that.